# convert a csv file into pointCloud type

Tags: python, matlab, lidar-data

I have a csv file for lidar data which contains the x, y, and z coordinates and the intensity like below:_

```
XCoord,YCoord,ZCoord,Intensity
-5436.108,-284.450,-13.281,33.0
-5436.786,-275.718,-15.141,33.0
-5302.184,-197.274,-0.927,34.0
-5308.833,-183.659,-2.696,33.0
-5309.803,-182.008,-4.463,34.0
-5320.611,-159.565,-5.858,34.0
-5323.79052,-153.348,-7.403,33.0
...............................................................
```

How is it possilbe to convert it to point of cloud type object?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with MATLAB, I explain it in that platform:
First, you need to load your input data matrix:

```
load('YourPointCloud.mat');
```

Then, use `pcwrite` function to save as `*.pcd` format:

```
pcwrite(ptCloud,'object3d.pcd','Encoding','ascii');
```

To try your result, you can load the saved file with:

```
pc = pcread('object3d.pcd');
```

Finally, visualise it with:

```
pcshow(pc);
```